# Possible reasons for one of my tables in PHP not displaying in Dreamweaver?

Tags: php

My code was originally working fine,with the table originally displaying perfectly on the page, but for some odd reason my one section of my code isn't displaying anymore in Dreamweaver. The table in question that isn't working is on the lower half of the page, does anyone see any noticeable errors in the code?

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1F-xakWDC5aA8fG0ionbrAtENZH5lMqTKCjb-d4VwIp8/edit

Comment: I havent used DW for years, but is it because PHP is serverside code and DW design view doesn't render it? The rest of your table code is HTML which is something that would be rendered no problem

Answer (score 1):

It's because you close `body` and `html` half way down the page, leaving `table` outside of the document.

Put

```
</body>
</html>
```

at the very bottom of your `php` file.

here:

```
Prescription Fee = <?php echo $prescript_lense[1

</br>
</p>
 </body> <!-- here -->
</html></p> <!-- and here -->
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
```

Not only that, but your php call doesn't even end!
`<?php echo $prescript_lense[1`.

Close it (`[1];?>`).

Comment: Actually, paragraphs and line breaks are not the same as they can have different layouts, sometimes done on purpose.

Answer (score 0):

Tons of bad code - from echoing image tags inside the head element, through having non-closed php tags with relevant code after them, to using tables for presentational purpose outside the body and even html tags.

That is the reason the table below isn't working - it's **outside the body and html tags** and **inside a php tag**.

Comment: and the unfinished php call!

Answer (score 0):

You're closing your `<body>` and `<html>` tags half way through your document. Anything outside of your `<html>` tags will not be rendered as content on your page and will be ignored.

If you close your `</body>` and your `</html>` tags after your table, you will be including this content before your page ends.